# Optimizing my knockout binding for my anchor link

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following knockout code:

```
<!-- ko if: isActive -->
<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: name" class="bg-color-blue fg-color-white"></a>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: isActive -->
<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: name" class="bg-color-grayLight"></a>
<!-- /ko -->
```

As you can see, this is the exact same anchor except the 'class' is different.

I wonder if it is possible to simplify my code to avoid duplicating this anchor? Is it possible to have one single anchor and set the condition inside?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`css` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):

```html
<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, 
              html: name, 
              css: { 'bg-color-grayLight': !isActive(), 
                     'bg-color-blue fg-color-white': isActive() }">
</a>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/16/

Alternatively you could use a conditional statement with the `attr` binding and set the entire class attribute:

```html
<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash, 'class': isActive() ? 
                  'bg-color-blue fg-color-white' : 'bg-color-grayLight' }, 
              html: name">
</a>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/17/

The downside of the second route, of course, is that any other classes will be removed when the binding is parsed. I'd stick with the first method.

Comment: This is nearly good: I noticed that when I have the same class to add on both side (isActive & !isActive) for example the class 'button' in my case, this class is only added for the first part. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/18/ when I added a class 'bold'. Try to check & uncheck the element and you'll see that the bold class is not used when checked. Any idea why? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato: That actually seems like a bug in the way KnockoutJS is adding/removing classes. However, I would just add the class to the `class` attribute on the element directly in a situation like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/19/

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for your help.